# Вирус. Полагаю что есть вирус на битрикс. Нужен безопасник

Tags: битрикс, вирусы

После проверки  модулем с маркета "Поиск троянов", ругается на файл, его содержимое показывает:

```
<?
        # CODE 400
        if (preg_match('#\$(USER|GLOBALS..USER..)->Authorize'.self::$spaces.'\([0-9]+\)#i', $str, $regs))
        {
            $LAST_REG = $regs[0];
            return '[400] bitrix auth';
        }


Подозрительный код
$USER->Authorize(1)
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Избранное");
?><?
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
    Loader::includeModule("sale");
     $delaydBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
        array(),
            array(
            "FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),
            "LID" => SITE_ID,
            "ORDER_ID" => "NULL",
            "DELAY" => "Y"
        ),
      array()
    );

    $arBasketItems = array();
        $dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
            array(
                "NAME" => "ASC",
                "ID" => "ASC"
            ),
     ..................
```

Причем, открываю файл через редактор этого вовсе нет в файле.

```
<?
        # CODE 400
        if (preg_match('#\$(USER|GLOBALS..USER..)->Authorize'.self::$spaces.'\([0-9]+\)#i', $str, $regs))
        {
            $LAST_REG = $regs[0];
            return '[400] bitrix auth';
        }


Подозрительный код
$USER->Authorize(1)
```

Где он может быть и как его редактировать вообще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$USER->Authorize(1)
```

Этот код авторизует человека который зайдет на эту прямую страницу под пользователем с id 1, как правило это администратор

Вам необходимо удалить строку $USER->Authorize(1), чтобы быть в безопасности.